# On converting "0X" (eg. "02", "00") strings to integer in r

Tags: r, dataframe, type-conversion

I have two columns `col32_Dokh` and `col32_Pesa` in a dataframe which contains `"00"`, `"01"`, ... Characters. I want to convert them to integer.

```
    df_integer <- transform(df_char, col32_Dokh = as.integer(col32_Dokh),
                                     col32_Pesa = as.integer(col32_Pesa))
```

but the conversion fails in this way:

[image: RStudio Result]
What's happening here? What should I you do to solve it?

Comment: make your table without the conditional stuff

Comment: I an amateur R user, I didn't get what you mean. Please explain more. @user12912834

Comment: examine what `df_integer$col32_Dokh == 0` is by itself.  You will see it is a  a logical vector.  So, when you tabulate a logical vector, you will have counts of TRUE and FALSE.  What you want is the table without the conditional part (`== 0`)

Comment: Got it! I'm neither good at English! @user12912834

Comment: Your original data is probably of class `factor`, which when converted to numeric is transformed into the factor number. Check the output of these: `a <- factor("02"); as.integer(a)` and `as.integer(as.character(a))`. If that's the case then just use `as.character` before `as.integer`, or, even better, make sure your data isn't loaded as factor.

Comment: You are right. See the post I added. There's even better way to solve the problem. @Molx

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418128/how-to-convert-a-factor-to-an-integer-numeric-without-a-loss-of-information), I found the answer:

```
col32_Pesa = as.numeric(levels(col32_Pesa))[col32_Pesa]
```